# Tabular format vs?

Tags: single-word-requests

If this is tabular format:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3
------------------------
Cell11   Cell12  Cell13
Cell21   Cell22  Cell23
```

What is this called?

```
Column1  Cell11
Column2  Cell12
Column3  Cell13
---------------
Column1  Cell21
Column2  Cell22
Column3  Cell23
```

It's not quite "pivoted". This would be pivoted:

```
         Row1    Row2
Column1  Cell11  Cell21 
Column2  Cell12  Cell22
Column3  Cell13  Cell23
```

Comment: It looks like a plain old *list* to me.

Comment: @HotLicks it is a bit like an HTML dl (Definition List)

Comment: If you want a computer term, ask on a computer board.

Comment: @HotLicks There is a "computing" tag here

Comment: That means it's computing-related, not that you're going to get a term that's valid computerese.  For jargon you need to ask other nerds.

Comment: @HotLicks okay forget the whole 'computing' part, this could apply to graphic design or magazine layouts too

Comment: Still looks like a *list* to me.

Comment: Note that a *table* is generally considered to be a 2-dimensional presentation, while a *list* is a 1-dimensional presentation.

Comment: For things in columns, there's 'columnar' but I can't think of a word for "in rows".

Comment: Maybe you call this a "Row-wise column-labeled list" or the table contents is in a row-wise column-labeled format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Hot Licks in the comments that what you are describing is a **list** format.

I have a precedent for this opinion from the computing world: In the Microsoft PowerShell scripting language, among the commands for formatting data for display are `Format-List` and `Format-Table`. These format the data in precisely the same way as you have described above.

For example, `Format-Table`:

```
PS C:\Users\dan> Get-Service | Select -First 3 Status,Name,DisplayName | Format-Table

 Status Name     DisplayName
 ------ ----     -----------
Stopped AJRouter AllJoyn Router Service
Stopped ALG      Application Layer Gateway Service
Stopped AppIDSvc Application Identity
```

And `Format-List`:

```
PS C:\Users\dan> Get-Service | Select -First 3 Status,Name,DisplayName | Format-List

Status      : Stopped
Name        : AJRouter
DisplayName : AllJoyn Router Service

Status      : Stopped
Name        : ALG
DisplayName : Application Layer Gateway Service

Status      : Stopped
Name        : AppIDSvc
DisplayName : Application Identity
```